# Sharing data between two instances in a load balanced java web application

Tags: ehcache

I want to cache data in a java web application deployed on multiple instances. We are using spring 2.5.6. What is the easiest caching library to configure and use with spring? I have heard of EH Cache, but the configuration is too cumbersome. 
The requirement is that a spring scheduler will run and set some flags. These flags are accessible from all load balanced instances. But since the scheduler runs only on one instance the flag is set only on that jvm. So how do i make these updated flag values available to all load balanced instances?

Answer (score 0):

We went from EHCache to Memcached. It's much easier to both configure and implement.